# Is there any evidence of a Jewish demon named Khoyzek?

Tags: language, etymology, yiddish, sheidim-demons, myths

The Yiddish term khoyzek refers a "mockery" of something else. According to Dov Sadan (cited [here](https://groups.google.com/g/jewish-languages/c/fQgby_9d0-Y/m/0cfgeyNABAAJ)) this word derives from Khoyzek a demon in Jewish folklore. I looked high and low and could not find any evidence of a demon name Khoyzek in any Jewish (or even non-Jewish sources). Does anybody know of any sources which mention such a demon?

Comment: Maybe it appears in A Treasury of Jewish Folklore? Or some other such book?

Comment: Perhaps this is something: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=HbMgubiK9BgC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=khoyzek+demon&source=bl&ots=OTlcULbV1C&sig=ACfU3U3Kx-TUkajeT_rST54fImXCNMPC0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi75M_IhMTsAhXoQxUIHT9rAM4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=khoyzek%20demon&f=false Or this (same book): https://books.google.co.il/books?id=HbMgubiK9BgC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=khoyzek+demon&source=bl&ots=OTlcULbV1C&sig=ACfU3U3Kx-TUkajeT_rST54fImXCNMPC0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi75M_IhMTsAhXoQxUIHT9rAM4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=khoyzek&f=false

Comment: If it's only found in Yidish, but not in standard Hebrew as well, then it might have a German origin, such as, say, *kotze(n)*, meaning *(to) puke*.

Comment: There is Middle High German *hoschen* - to mock

Comment: כויזעק indeed means mockery in Yiddish